# Spring boot application validate against two different okta authorization servers

Tags: spring-boot, okta

We have a requirement where we have two client applications (A,B) sharing one back-end Java application(Spring Boot)(C). Client A should have access to all the apis of C . But client B should have restrictive access.

Application A & B should be authenticated by different okta servers. C should validate access tokens from both the clients.

Can Spring boot application validate against two different okta authorization servers ? Please guide me how can i achieve this requirement from okta setup.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like this example: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/. Where they use Facebook and GitHub to login.